# Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Decodable, from: Data)'

Tags: swift, generics, associated-types, jsondecoder

I have the following example code in a Playground. I want to decode the result of a network request if that result conforms to the `Decodable` protocol.

Any idea why this code does not work?

```
protocol APIRequest {
    associatedtype Result
}

func execute<T: APIRequest>(request: T) {
    if let decodableResult = T.Result.self as? Decodable {
        try JSONDecoder().decode(decodableResult, from: Data())
    }
}
```

I am getting the error `Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Decodable, from: Data)'` on this line: `try JSONDecoder().decode(decodableResult, from: Data())`

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `JSONDecoder.decode(_:from:)` method requires a concrete type conforming to `Decodable` as its input argument. You need to add an extra type constraint to `T.Result` to make it `Decodable`.

```
func execute<T: APIRequest>(request: T) throws where T.Result: Decodable {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(T.Result.self, from: Data())
}
```

Btw what's the point of trying to decode an empty `Data` instance?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. There is no point in decoding from empty data, this is just a proof of concept in Playground. The reason why I don’t want to add a type constraint is because I want to have certain requests with result types which are not decodable. Any way around this?

Comment: @BalázsVincze you should overload the `execute(request:)` to have a version of it specifically for not `Decodable` compliant `T.Result`