# Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Codable.Type?

Tags: json, swift, deserialization, jsondecoder

I'm refactoring (*trying to*) some network code made by an ex-colleague and I wanted to use the new `JSONDecoder`.

His network code is wrapped into a function `getData`:

```
func getData(modelToReturn:Proto.Type, configuredRequest:URLRequest) {
```

As you can see from the signature, in this method you could specify the model to return (that is which model is supposed to deserialize the retrieved JSON: I can't say it better, I hope you understood anyway   :-)   ).

In this case, `Proto` is the protocol any model conforms to.

eg.

```
struct GroceryModel:Proto{
  //...
}
```

The method was then called this way:

```
net.getData(modelToReturn: GroceryModel.self, configuredRequest: grocery)
```

Once called, `GroceryModel.self` was assigned to a member of the `net` class (`memberToReturn:Proto.Type?`) and then the JSON tested for conformance against a model struct with a failable initializer:

```
 if let instance = modelToReturn?.init(json:jsonResult){...
```

I made a little test with the following protocol:

```
struct Test: Codable {
    let name: String
    let testers: [String]
}
```

and I replaced much of the original code with this single line:

```
let test = try? JSONDecoder().decode(modelToReturn, from: jsonData)
```

My idea was to pass `Codable.self` as the first parameter of the `getData` function but I got an error on this last line:

```
Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Codable.Type?, from: Data)'
```

So, how can I properly pass my model, so that it can be used from the `decode` function?

I must say, I manually tested that line by simply replacing `modelToReturn` with `Test.self` and the error disappears.

Comment: `modelToReturn` cannot be `optional`. You cannot just pass `Codable.self`, you have to pass the type that was passed in. If you just pass `Codable`, the function won't know what to decode.

Comment: Your issue seems pretty similar to [Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Decodable, from: Data)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307524/cannot-invoke-decode-with-an-argument-list-of-type-decodable-from-data/54307611#comment95435498_54307611), the answer should help you as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor: thanks, I haven't found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generics like below.

```
protocol Proto {
}

struct Test: Codable, Proto {
    let name: String
    let testers: [String]
}

func getData<T>(type: T.Type, configuredRequest:URLRequest?) where T : Decodable {
    let data = """
{
    "name": "a test",
    "testers": ["mike", "bob"],
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
    let test = try? JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
    debugPrint(test)
}

getData(type: Test.self, configuredRequest: nil)
```

---

Edited.

As commented, you want Type to be a member of the class, which has `getData`.
In that case you can apply generics to class definition like below.

```
class DataFetcher<T> where T: Decodable {
    func getData(configuredRequest:URLRequest?) {
        let data = """
{
    "name": "a test",
    "testers": ["mike", "bob"],
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
        let test = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        debugPrint(test)
    }
}

DataFetcher<Test>().getData(configuredRequest: nil)
```

Comment: This does not solve another issue: what should be the type of the member of the class? I tried Decodable? (optional) and then, when I had to assign its value, XCode forced me to do it this way: T.Type.self as? Decodable, but this way the error is still there, in the decode function.

Comment: What do you mean with "the member of the class"? For example, in my code which class do you make Optional<Decotable>?

Comment: As I explained, I assign the value of type to a member of the class where I have the method getData, for later use

Comment: so you removed the first argument and directly passed the model in DataFetcher<Test>: but my class DataFetcher creates an instance in the viewController because of delegation and separation of concerns. Is it possible to create an instance of DataFetcher?

Comment: Ok, I tried the instantiation and it works. I even tried to store the value in a member this way var `s:T.Type = T.self` (is it ok?) and it works

Comment: The only drawback is flexibility, but anyway thanks, you helped me a lot   :-)